# Pyspark ml can't fit the model and always "AttributeError: 'PipelinedRDD' object has no attribute '_jdf'

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

```
data = sqlContext.sql("select a.churn,b.pay_amount,c.all_balance from db_bi.t_cust_churn a left join db_bi.t_cust_pay b on a.cust_id=b.cust_id left join db_bi.t_cust_balance c on a.cust_id=c.cust_id limit 5000").cache()

def labelData(df):
    return df.map(lambda row: LabeledPoint(row[0], row[1:]))
traindata = labelData(data) --this step works well.
from pyspark.ml.classification import LogisticRegression   
lr = LogisticRegression(maxIter=10, regParam=0.3, elasticNetParam=0.8)
lrModel = lr.fit(lrdata)
lrModel = lr.fit(lrdata)
```

---

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-b84a106121e6> in <module>()
----> 1 lrModel = lr.fit(lrdata)

/home/hadoop/spark/python/pyspark/ml/pipeline.pyc in fit(self, dataset, params)
     67                 return self.copy(params)._fit(dataset)
     68             else:
---> 69                 return self._fit(dataset)
     70         else:
     71             raise ValueError("Params must be either a param map or a list/tuple of param maps, "

/home/hadoop/spark/python/pyspark/ml/wrapper.pyc in _fit(self, dataset)
    131 
    132     def _fit(self, dataset):
--> 133         java_model = self._fit_java(dataset)
    134         return self._create_model(java_model)
    135 

/home/hadoop/spark/python/pyspark/ml/wrapper.pyc in _fit_java(self, dataset)
    128         """
    129         self._transfer_params_to_java()
--> 130         return self._java_obj.fit(dataset._jdf)
    131 
    132     def _fit(self, dataset):

AttributeError: 'PipelinedRDD' object has no attribute '_jdf'
```

Comment: lrModel = lr.fit(lrdata) - is this a typo? it should be traindata you want to fit, right?

Comment: Sorry.My fault. I means lrModel = lr.fit(traindata)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are using the tutorial for the latest spark version [(2.0.1)](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-classification-regression.html) with 
`pyspark.ml.classification import LogisticRegression` whereas you need some other version, e.g. [1.6.2](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/mllib-linear-methods.html) with `pyspark.mllib.classification import LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS, LogisticRegressionModel`. Note the different libraries.